# firebase-What if the valueEventListner fires every millisecond?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am saving total user count in my app and displaying in my app.

But now I only have like 100 users but I am wondering if my users increase and let's say they all go offline in the interval of 1 sec.

What will be the effect of this on my app?
Will my app freeze or something?

Is it wrong to attach value event listener on value like this, which updates so fast?
And if it is wrong how I keep it updated, should I Use the timer or something?

or how will it effect my charges/pricing?

EDIT

I attached code I am using

```
  private void getUserCount(){

    myRef.child("usersCount").child("total").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.getValue() != null){

                Long onlineUsersCountLong = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);
                sharedPrefMain.saveOnlineUsersCount(onlineUsersCountLong);
                if (onlineUsersCountLong != null) {

                    onlineUsersCount.setText(Long.toString(onlineUsersCountLong) + " ");

                } else {

                    onlineUsersCount.setText("1 ");
                }

            }else{
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                onlineUsersCount.setText("1 ");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It's hard to answer without seeing the actual code that you're asking about. Please have a look at [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hello @FrankvanPuffelen, I updated my question please take a look.

Comment: Thanks for that. That code looks fine to me. What's your specific concern on what will happen in this code when users disconnect?

Comment: When the user disconnects(goes offline) then online user count changes(decrease by 1), but I want to know when my app expand and if all my users go to decide offline at once then what will happen.....means how many times this event listener will be fired and some other simple doubts you can see in question.

Comment: Hello @FrankvanPuffelen, I am publishing my app tomorrow, can you please help me clear my doubts

Comment: I think that your app shall be fine with the "Flame plan". It will cost you around 25$/month (https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) and it supports 100,000 simultaneous connections.

Comment: The proper way of handling the firebase data change listener is to couple it with the life cycle of your activity/fragment. The concern that "how many updates per sec/minute" is irrelevant. As far as the updates arrive to your concerned fragment/activity keep changing the values, it wouldn't affect your app.

Comment: Also your question is unclear/broad, you are not specific and asking for a opinion based answer "Will my app freeze, etc".

Comment: @SalmanKhakwani I know it will not affect my app but i think it will effect my cost

Comment: Umm, so you have released your app today? I think that your Fiirebsae cost wouldn't cross 25$ until you get 100,000+ active users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using valueEventListner I used **listnerFoSingleEvent** in **onResume()** of my activity and that's how I keep my data refresh without worrying of too many calls on valueEventListner